# Finding if a number is prime

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, primes

I just started a java course. The task is to write a code that will output whether a number is prime or not.

This is what I have. It comes up with a lot of errors. I have found a lot of answers but they all say to use lines that we haven't learnt.

```
public class PrimeNumbers2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 9;
    int count = 2;
    Boolean prime = true;

    if (number % count == 0) {
        prime = true;
    }
    else {

        for (count = count + 1) {

        if (count + 1>= number) {
            prime = false;
        }
        else
        {
            prime =  false;
        }

    }
    if (prime == true)
    {
        System.out.println("Number is prime");
    }
     else
    {
        System.out.println("number is not prime");
    }
}}}
```

Comment: Post your code here. Not a picture of it.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557) (thank you for editing the code into your question)

Comment: edited it, sorry.

Comment: This --> `for (count = count + 1)` won't compile

Comment: Juan what would be there instead, if anything?

Comment: One thing I noticed immediately is that it doesn't seem like your for-loop is structured correctly. It needs to have some sort of terminating condition, e.g. for(count; count < 0; count--) or something

Comment: I'm sure that this question has been answered before

Comment: what do you mean by not structured correctly? when i put for(count; count < 0; count--) it tells me the first count isnt a statement? im getting more and more confused, haha

Comment: jwils i put in the question that it has been, but with lines we havent learnt in class yet :)

Comment: Paraoxic My bad, the first statement needs to be a proper initialization expression, `[some variable] = [some number]`, ie, `for (count = 0; count < 16; count++)` or `for (int x = 100; x > 0; x--)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple bugs and logic errors in your code.  Here it is cleaned up.

```
int number = 15;
int count = 2;
boolean prime = true;


for (int i = count; i <= number/2; i++ ) {

   if (number % i == 0) {
      prime = false;
  }
}


if (prime == true)
{
    System.out.println("Number is prime");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("number is not prime");
}
```

Comment: thankyou so much for this, the only trouble im now having is understanding "i" , what does it actually mean / stand for ?

Comment: The for statement reads like this: 

start at 2 go up by 1 until you reach number/2.

i is the variable that starts at 2 and goes up by 1 each time. So for the first iteration of the loop it is 2 and it runs: 15%2 == 0.  Then after it is done with that iteration it increments i to 3 and then runs 15%3 == 0.  It keeps going up 1 each time until it reaches number/2 then the for loop ends.

Comment: @Paraoxic Here is a good tutorial to read on the for statement: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 1):

You should think about how you would formulate your problem in natural language. For example: *A prime number is a number that is only dividable by itself and 1.* or the other way around: *For every number in the range of bigger then 1 and smaller then my number, there should be no divider*.

To formulate your problem now in simple java code, try to implement your statement.

```
   for(int count=2; count < number; count++) {
      if(number % count == 0) {
          System.out.println("Number is not a prime!");
          // Since we are finished return and do no more iterations
          return;
      }
   }
   // we iterated all possible numbers and can return successfully
   System.out.println("Number is a prime");
```

Make also sure to check the edge cases in advance. E.g. negative numbers.
Please note that is an inefficient solution but the straight forward one.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about a super simple implementation here, you could first check to see if the number is even using the remainder operator, i.e., if `number % 2 == 0`, then `prime = true`. If that is not the case, set `count = 3` and set up a `while` loop with the terminating condition `while (count < number)`. Within the `while` loop, check to see if the remainder of `number` and `count` is zero. If it is, it's a prime number. If not, increment `count` by one and the loop continues.

Comment: hi thankyou for commenting, im about 6 lessons into the course and when i say basic i mean really basic as we havent done while loops either, are there any substitutes i could use ?

Comment: The same thing could be done with a `for` loop, i.e, `for (count = 3; count < number; count++)`

Comment: thankyou for explaining that, much appreciated. Think i have it sorted now
!